# RichTextBox removing images in windows 8

Tags: .net, image, windows-8, richtextbox

My application uses the RichTextBox control (.Net 3.5) to edit RTF documents. In Windows XP to 7 all works fine, but on Windows 8 the RichTextBox for some reason does not load images: if there is an image in the rtf file, then the control will remove it when loading the file (whether by using the Load method or manually changing the Rtf property to the document's rtf code).

Is there any explanation why this happens? Or how it can be resolved?

---

**Edit:** *(detailed explanation on how to recreate the issue)*

I used a simple rtf file, with a single .bmp image in it (and nothing else).

The application is an *empty* .net 3.5 application, with a single button and a single textbox, with the following code in the button's Click Event:

```
Dim rtb as new RichTextBox
rtb.LoadFile("C:\2.rtf")
TextBox1.Text = rtb.Rtf
```

When run, after I click the button the following appears in the textbox:

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset177{\*\fname Times 
New Roman;}Times New Roman (Hebrew);}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\rtlpar\nowidctlpar\qc\lang1037\kerning1\f0\rtlch\fs24\par
}
```

As you can see, the image is omitted.

I use Visual Studio 2008 (with VB.net 3.5), on a windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: Works just fine when I try it on Windows 8.1 Update 1.  Your question gives no cue whatsoever why you are having a problem.  Pretty important to provide a sample .rtf file with this problem as well as a snippet that shows it being loaded.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited the post and included detailed explanation. I did not add an rtf file since the file is empty and just includes a single image (the issue occurred no matter what image was in the file).